# Refactoring if-else statements checking for different file extensions

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this piece of code which i feel could be cleaned up ( i could be wrong) but i wanted to see if anyone has a suggestion how i can change this to be "better"

```
string getExt = Path.GetExtension(DocumentUNCPath.Text);
        var convertFileId = Guid.NewGuid();
        var convertFilePath = @"c:\temp\" + convertFileId + ".pdf";


        if (getExt == ".doc" || getExt == ".docx" || getExt == ".txt" || getExt == ".rtf")
        {
            WordToPdf(convertFilePath);

        }
        else if (getExt == ".xlsx" || getExt == ".xls")
        {
            ExcelToPdf(convertFilePath);
        }
        else if (getExt == ".jpg" || getExt == ".png" || getExt == ".jpeg" || getExt == ".JPG" || getExt == ".PNG")
        {
            ImgToPDF(convertFilePath);
        }
```

Comment: I think it's enough good to use it.

Comment: At a minimum, do `getExt = getExt.ToLower()` and remove te redundant etensions from the conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following may initially be more code, but can scale better.

Outside of method:

```
    public static readonly List<string> WorkExtensions = new List<string> { ".doc", ".docx", ".txt", ".trf" };
    public static readonly List<string> ExcelExtensions = new List<string> { ".xlsx", ".xls" };
    public static readonly List<string> ImageExtensions = new List<string> { ".jpg", ".png", ".jpeg" };
```

Inside of method:

```
    string getExt = Path.GetExtension(DocumentUNCPath.Text);
    var convertFileId = Guid.NewGuid();
    var convertFilePath = @"c:\temp\" + convertFileId + ".pdf";

    getExt = getExt.ToLower();

    if (WorkExtensions.Contains(getExt))
    {
        WordToPdf(convertFilePath)
    }
    else if (ExcelExtensions.Contains(getExt))
    {
        ExcelToPdf(convertFilePath);
    }
    else if (ImageExtensions.Contains(getExt))
    {
        ImgToPdf(convertFilePath);
    }
```

Answer (score 15):

Map of extension to handler is standard approach for such cases:

```
// populate with { ".doc", WordToPdf } and similar pairs
Dictionary<string, Action<string> > handlers = ... 


// find and call handler by extension 
// (use TryGetValue to check for existence if needed)
handlers[getExt]( convertFilePath );
```

Comment: I would add that since file names are not case sensitive to make the comparison of the extension case insensitive as well. i.e.  `new Dictionary<string, Action<string>>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Comment: Would it make more sense to be a `List<string>` rather than `string` for the key value? This is in case you wanted multiple extensions to go to the same action.

Comment: @gunr2171 No it wouldn't make sense to use `List<string>` as the key, it would actually defeat the purpose of using a `Dictionary`.  In using a `List<string>` you make the look up slower, because you would need to check each key till you found the key that contains the desired extension, then return that value at that key.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this

```
    switch (getExt.ToUpper()) 
    {    
       case "JPG":    
       case "PNG": 
....
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the `Dictionary<string, Action<string>>` answer above is the most elegant answer, but just for completeness, here's a solution via a string extension:

```
public static class StringExt
{
    public static bool MatchesAnyOf(this string text, params string[] targets)
    {
        return targets.Any(target => string.Compare(text, target, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);
    }
}
```

Then you can write the code like this:

```
if (getExt.MatchesAnyOf(".doc", ".doxc", ".txt", ".rtf"))
{
    WordToPdf(convertFilePath);
}
else if (getExt.MatchesAnyOf(".xlsx", ".xls"))
{
    ExcelToPdf(convertFilePath);
}
else if (getExt.MatchesAnyOf(".jpg", ".png", ".jpeg", ".JPG", ".PNG")
{
    ImgToPDF(convertFilePath);
}
```

This implementation ignores case and culture, which is appropriate for filenames, but would not be appropriate for general use - so real code would probably have to provide overloads for specifying culture and comparison type.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for extensiblity, you could conisder something like this:

```
public struct Converter {
  public string         Extension;
  public Action<string> ConvertAction;
}

public static class Extensions {
  static Action<string> WordToPdf  = (s) => {;};
  static Action<string> ExcelToPdf = (s) => {;};
  static Action<string> ImgToPdf   = (s) => {;};

  public static IEnumerable<Converter> Converters = new List<Converter> {
    new Converter {Extension = ".doc",  ConvertAction = WordToPdf},
    new Converter {Extension = ".docx", ConvertAction = WordToPdf},
    new Converter {Extension = ".txt",  ConvertAction = WordToPdf},
    new Converter {Extension = ".rtf",  ConvertAction = WordToPdf},

    new Converter {Extension = ".xls",  ConvertAction = ExcelToPdf},
    new Converter {Extension = ".xlsx", ConvertAction = ExcelToPdf},

    new Converter {Extension = ".jpg",  ConvertAction = ImgToPdf},
    new Converter {Extension = ".png",  ConvertAction = ImgToPdf},
    new Converter {Extension = ".jpeg", ConvertAction = ImgToPdf},
    new Converter {Extension = ".doc",  ConvertAction = ImgToPdf}
  };

  public void RunIt(string extension, string convertFilePath) {
    extension = extension.ToLower();
    var action = ( from a in Converters 
                   where a.Extension.Equals(extension) 
                   select a.ConvertAction).First();
    if (action != null) action(convertFilePath);
  }
}
```

Comment: I learned something new today. wow! this looks very neat even though it is more code than what i started with but i will try this out as well. Thanks!

Comment: It is more code at this point, but add a few nore extensions and you hit a break-even point. Plus, being data-driven, it could be loaded at run-time from an external text file.