# If statement to filter file extensions (C#)

Tags: c#, image, if-statement, picturebox, file-extension

I want to proceed in creating a program that does different events with different file extensions, with files opened with . I understand things like Path.GetExtension, and these answers: [Refactoring if-else statements checking for different file extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144320/refactoring-if-else-statements-checking-for-different-file-extensions)
[C# custom file extension filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66681658/c-sharp-custom-file-extension-filter)

Can someone explain me a straight forward how to create a button "If Statement" meant at executing say, if a ".jpeg" file is detected as the selected file's extension, while "else" may bring up message box, like "Improper File type uploaded."

Here is cut of the code where action takes place:

```
private void BtnMediaPlayer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Open File Dialog
    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    // Image Filters
    open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp";
    if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // display image in picture box  
        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(open.FileName);


    }



}
```

As can be seen, the program opens an Open File Dialog that then is supposed to filter for certain files, and then Open them within the pciture box, but how do I rewrite it so that, *"if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)"* or the surrounding code produces different results (executions based on the If Statements) based on the file type(s)?

TL DR
How to write If Statements for Different files uploaded?

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding what the problem is.. Why can't you just write these if statements to check the extension? This sounds super trivial so I feel like I don't fully get what is being asked here.

Comment: The dialog does not return you filtered files.  The filter property is used to initially limit what the end user sees, namely a filtered list.  But the end user can override your filter, with say *.*, and then select something not in your original filter.

Comment: Updated, TLDR how to write If Statements for different fule types?

Comment: You're asking how to write if statements..? You just write them the same as you would for comparing any other string values. It's a very simple/early C# topic. Is there anything specific about it that is causing you trouble?

Comment: First step: did the user select something? You already handled that by checking for OK. Next step: inspect the extension and react accordingly,  either with a bunch of ifs, or with a case statement

Comment: I'll try it, I just wanted assurance into if files can be integrated into if statements, and if any of you could demonstrate, please gladly do so.

Comment: Think of it as two parts, the first part is to use the `OpenFileDialog` to get a file name as a string, and the second part is to take the filename and compare it using typical conditional statements, e.g. `if/else` or `switch/case`. Note, the `OpenFileDialog` returns filenames as strings, you just need to pick off the extension part of the `OpenFileDialog.FileName` and compare the string's parts you care about, e.g. the filename extension to your list of valid extensions.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void BtnMediaPlayer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Filter = OpenFileImageFilter;
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if (IsValidImageFile(ofd.FileName))
        {
            // display image in picture box  
            pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid file type selected.");
        }
    }
}

// array of image formats so we can use it in OpenFileDialog filter
// and in our IsValidImageFile method
private string[] ImageFormats => new[] { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".bmp" };

// helper method to turn array of image extensions into OpenFileDialog filter string
private string OpenFileImageFilter
{
    get
    {
        string fileExts = "";
        foreach (string s in ImageFormats)
        {
            fileExts += $"*{s};";
        }
        return $"Image Files({fileExts})|{fileExts}";
    }
}

// reusable method that uses the ImageFormats property to check file extension
private bool IsValidImageFile(string filename)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename)) return false;
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(filename);
    return ImageFormats.Contains(extension);
}
```